# Neo4j - Web-Admin shows wrong node/relationship/properties count

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I encounter a very weird behavior of neo4j, where it reports wrong number of nodes, relationships and properties, which were never were created by anyone (It happened to me both on `neo4j-community-1.9-windows` and `neo4j-community-2.0.0-M03-windows`). So that's the scenario:

I downloaded and unpacked the package, launched the command-prompt, and entered `neo4j install`. It all goes smooth, and when I open localhost:7474, i get the following:
[image]
*(nodes: 1, properties: 0, relationships: 0, relationship types: 0)*

All is fine till now.

Next, I enter `neo4j stop`, wait for it to stop, and then enter again `neo4j start`. After that, the WebAdmin shows the following:

[image]
*(nodes: 1, properties: 1, relationships: 1, relationship types: 0)*

Repeating another cycle of `neo4j stop/start`, produce the following:

[image]
*(nodes: 5093, properties: 1, relationships: 1, relationship types: 0)*

This is very weird... anyone knows why it happens or whether it's a bug or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, the numbers shown in webadmin are not exact counts it's a display of the highest id in use.

Comment: but i never created any other node, and i never created any relationship, so why the IDs changed?

Comment: not sure but it might be possible that on startup a bunch of ids is acquired for internal reasons.